# Python: Type error while using exec for creating TKINTER Checkbutton

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a checkbox using a loop(using dropbox files_list_folder('').entries) and get the text & status if it is checked, but it is showing TypeError and the problem is i need to assign var to get status of the checkbutton:

```
for ii,j in zip(range(len(files_list)),range(1,len(files_list)+1)):
    exec("var%i=StringVar()"%j)
    exec("ch%i = Checkbutton(text=files_list[ii],variable=var%i)"%j%j)
    exec("ch%i.grid(row=ii, column=0, sticky=W)"%j)
```

Comment: What's the TypeError you're seeing?

Comment: TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: You should never use exec like this, it makes your code nearly impossible to read and debug. Store your widgets in a dictionary or list instead.  see [How do I create a variable number of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: yes i understand, but whenever it is checked i need its text, thats y i need a var=StringVar() to be asigned to every checkbutton i create

Comment: I think it's because you're using `%` as a percent character in your format string. I believe you need to use `%%` instead.

Comment: No i m using it as a integer %i like ch1,ch2,ch3, and variable =var1, variable=var2,,,,etc

Comment: I am not sure why you are using `exec`. Checkbuttons are more than capable of providing what you need without the use of `exec`. Instead of trying to assign variable names through `exec` you should just append a list with each checkbutton and var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid the use of `exec` and `eval` whenever possible. These are very unsafe to someone who does not fully understand what they can do. Both have a severe risk of code injection.

You can use list to get results of each `Checkbutton` selection. We can store the `StringVar()` in a list and then call that value when button is checked or unchecked.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

value_list = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
var_list = []

def print_results_from_selection(i):
    print("{}: {}".format(value_list[i], var_list[i].get()))

def generate_buttons():
    for i in range(len(value_list)):
        var_list.append(tk.StringVar())
        var_list[-1].set(0)
        tk.Checkbutton(root, text=value_list[i], variable=var_list[-1],
                       command=lambda i=i: print_results_from_selection(i),
                       onvalue=1, offvalue=0).grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="w")

generate_buttons()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @balabharath glad to help. Be sure to select the check button next to my answer if it solved your problem. This will let everyone know you have got a solution to your question.